# Creating a custom Jquery modal form to upload data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery-ui

i am new to jquery.I looked to various demos but can't find what i am looking for.

I have a button.I want to add a functionality in which button Onclick would open a modal form through which a user can upload various details about a particular item like it's name,size,colour,brand,cost,images,description.

After filling the details these various fields will be stored in a mysql database using a php file.

I want to make this custom dialog form on the same principle as the form on jquery website.
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

I tried making a custom dialog form using the example in the above hyperlink but not being able to create one..

Please help.

Comment: You should post the code you used, from your description the jquery ui modal looks very close to what you want

Answer (score 0):

The example on the page you linked is created by using jQuery UI, if you click the "view source" link on the page, it will show you how to do it (how it is created in their page).

I would suggest, though, to use a modal that would be easier to implement for a new user, [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), for example as it has clear examples on how to implement on their site and it will get you up and running much faster.

Comment: i need to create a form in which the end user of the website can upload various images of different sizes and format along with other details about the particular item.Fancybox only provides a method to display images beautifully not uploading functionality.

Comment: Fancybox provides the ability to show an iframe or inline content. By using either of these you would be able to display a html form with the ability to upload files and submit data.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the UI pack for this , else you can do this by creating j query simple calls
1. onclick show form
2. on save send a ajax call
3.after saving record the function you have generated to fetch records from db call it, it will display the updated record from db.
i personally suggest you to make it your self for better understanding for work its just simple and easy
if you use UI then you have to make changes to it for as your requirement and that's also too easy.